# Show at least one online item from array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of users which i have sorted by distance. I want to display the 5 nearest items but sometimes the 5 nearest items all have "offline" state, in which case i want to ensure at least 1 "online" item is added also.

Here is my attempt so far which isn't quite working. It didn't show the 5 "offline" items plus 1 "online" item like i wanted,  it showed all.

```
var items = 0;
var online = usersOnline();
var itemsOnline = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < nearest.length; i++) {
    var item = nearest[i];
    if ( items < 5 ) { 
        items++;
        if ( item.state != "offline" ) { itemsOnline++; }
        jQuery( "#leaflet-control-geosearch-results" ).append( "<li id='record-"+item.label+"'><label><input type='checkbox' class='cb' value='"+item.id+"'>&nbsp;<img src='img/presence/"+item.state+"_map.png' height='10px'> "+item.label+" ("+parseFloat(item.distance  / 1000).toFixed(2)+strings[strLang].nearestMetre+")</label><div class='icons'><a title='"+strings[strLang].nearestLocate+"' class='locate' href='"+item.label+"'><img src='img/icons/locate.png' height='15px' /></a>&nbsp;<a title='"+strings[strLang].routeGet+"' class='directions' href='"+item.label+"'><img src='img/icons/directions.png' height='15px' /></a></div><div class='clear'></div></li>" );
    }
}
while (( online > 0 ) && ( itemsOnline < 1 )) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nearest.length; i++) {
        var item = nearest[i];
        if ( item.state != "offline" ) { 

            itemsOnline++; }
            jQuery( "#leaflet-control-geosearch-results" ).append( "<li id='record-"+item.label+"'><label><input type='checkbox' class='cb' value='"+item.id+"'>&nbsp;<img src='img/presence/"+item.state+"_map.png' height='10px'> "+item.label+" ("+parseFloat(item.distance  / 1000).toFixed(2)+strings[strLang].nearestMetre+")</label><div class='icons'><a title='"+strings[strLang].nearestLocate+"' class='locate' href='"+item.label+"'><img src='img/icons/locate.png' height='15px' /></a>&nbsp;<a title='"+strings[strLang].routeGet+"' class='directions' href='"+item.label+"'><img src='img/icons/directions.png' height='15px' /></a></div><div class='clear'></div></li>" );
        }
    }                           
}
```

Comment: I usually do this in the select query on a user database.  I actually have a query that will allow you to enter a zip and distance and find all users given that distance near by. You would just want to modify an additional conditional: online = true or something.

Give me a few moments and i will see if i can do it in javascript

Comment: is it failing in the for loop or the while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the whole thing with just one pass/loop:

Try:

```
var items = 0;
var online = usersOnline();
var itemsOnline = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < nearest.length; i++) {
    var item = nearest[i];

    if (item.state != "offline") {
        itemsOnline++;
    } else if (items >= 5) {
        // we already have 5 items, so we're now only interested in online items. this new one is an offline one, so skip it
        continue;
    }

    items++;
    jQuery( "#leaflet-control-geosearch-results" ).append( "<li id='record-"+item.label+"'><label><input type='checkbox' class='cb' value='"+item.id+"'>&nbsp;<img src='img/presence/"+item.state+"_map.png' height='10px'> "+item.label+" ("+parseFloat(item.distance  / 1000).toFixed(2)+strings[strLang].nearestMetre+")</label><div class='icons'><a title='"+strings[strLang].nearestLocate+"' class='locate' href='"+item.label+"'><img src='img/icons/locate.png' height='15px' /></a>&nbsp;<a title='"+strings[strLang].routeGet+"' class='directions' href='"+item.label+"'><img src='img/icons/directions.png' height='15px' /></a></div><div class='clear'></div></li>" );

    if (items >= 5 && itemsOnline >= 1) {
        // we've now got at least 5 items, and at least 1 is online, so we're done.
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loops condition only gets evaluated after the inner for loop has completed iterating through the entire `nearest` array.

Since you only need to itterate the through the `nearest` array once to get an online item, you can replace the while loop with an if statement:

```
if (itemsOnline < 1) {
    for (var i = 5; i < nearest.length; i++) { // start from 6th element
        var item = nearest[i];
        if (item.state != "offline") {
            jQuery("#leaflet-control-geosearch-results").append(etc);
            break; // exit loop
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var items = 0;
var online = usersOnline();
var itemsOnline = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < nearest.length && items < 5; i++, items++ ) {
    var item = nearest[i];
    items++;
    if ( item.state != "offline" ) { itemsOnline++; }
    apendItem( item );
}
for ( var i = 5; i < nearest.length && itemsOnline < 1; i++ ) {
    var item = nearest[i];
    apendItem( item );
    break;
}
```